# Easy way to know which method is best one

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I am new to prestashop, i have my html template design for my shop , my question is which method of workflow is  easy to work for pretashop , Being with html template design add new  theme for my site  or modify the existing default theme as per the design. can anyone give me nice suggestion for this question , Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice it to copy the default theme and customize it.

From the official PrestaShop documentation:

> Building a PrestaShop is a complex endeavour. For instance, in comparison with a WordPress theme, which could work with a single index.php file, a minimal PrestaShop requires many more pages: home page, product page, user account pages, cart page, order process pages, etc. Building a theme for an e-commerce site implies a much more complex and intertwined set of pages and templates.
>
> This is why we advise to start your own theme by using the foundations laid by the default theme. Complete and proven, PrestaShop's default theme ensures that all necessary pages are already in places, leaving you the freedom to rework the page display, to use your own images, to enhance it with your own scripts.

More info: [Creating your own theme](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+your+own+theme)

Comment: Ok i will go through the default theme for changing my own html template to prestashop, for changing those html to prestashop i can't able to find a proper tutorials for that , can you guide me some best links for that, thanks  .

Comment: @Karthickdev This is the best I could find: [PrestaShop Theming Explained](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/prestashop-theming-explained--net-28414)